# Default GCC optimization options for a specific architecture

Tags: gcc

our compilers course features exercises asking us to compare code built with the -O and -O3 gcc options. The code generated by my machine isn't the same as the code in the course. Is there a way to figure the optimization options used in the course, in order to obtain the same code on my machine, and make more meaningful observations?

I found how to get the optimization options on my machine :

```
$ gcc -O3 -Q --help=optimizer
```

But is there a way to deduce those on the machine of the professor except by trying them all and modifying them one by one (.ident "GCC: (Debian 4.3.2-1.1) 4.3.2")?

Thanks for your attention.

Edit:
I noticed that the code generated on my machine lacks the prologue and epilogue generated on my professor's. Is there an option to force prologue generation (google doesn't seem to bring much)?

Comment: Several distributions are *patching* the FSF source code of GCC. So a Debian GCC might be different from a CentOS one, even with the same version number! Or you could compile the FSF source code.

Comment: Hehe trying all options until I get the same code will probably be faster :D

Comment: Some optimizations included in -Ox can not be selected on their own (there is no such switch). Details here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to know about compiler optimizations : they are architecture dependent. Also, they're mainly different from one version of the compiler to another (*gcc-4.9* does more stuff by default than *gcc-4.4*).
By architecture, I mean CPU micro architecture (**Intel** : *Nehalem, Sandy bridge, Ivy Bridge, Haswell, KNC* ... **AMD** : *Bobcat, Bulldozzer, Jaguar,* ...). Compilers usually convert input code (**C**, **C++**, **ADA**, ...) into a *CPU-agnostic* intermediary representation (**GIMPLE** for *GCC*) on which a large number of optimizations will be performed. After that, the compiler will generate a lower level representation closer to assembly. On the latter, architecture specific optimizations will be unrolled. Such optimizations include the choice of instructions with the lowest latencies, determining loop unroll factors depending on the loop size, the instruction cache size, and so on.
Since your generated code is different from the one you got in class, I suppose the underlying architectures must be different. In this case, even with the same compiler flags you won't be able to get the same assembly code (even with no optimizations you'll get different assembly codes).
For that, you should concentrate on comparing the optimized and non-optimized codes rather than trying to stick to what you were given in class. I even think that it's a great reverse engineering exercise to compare your optimized code to the one you were given.
You can find one of my earlier posts about compiler optimizations in [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4011/assembly-code-gcc-optimized-vs-not/4136#4136). 
Two great books on the subject are **The Dragon Book** (*Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools*) by Aho, Seti, and Ulman, and also **Engineering a Compiler** by Keith Cooper, and Linda Torczon.